# Sharing a ctypes numpy array without lock when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a large array (~500k rows x 9 columns) which I would like to share when running a number of parallel processes using Python's `multiprocessing` module. I am using [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549190/is-shared-readonly-data-copied-to-different-processes-for-python-multiprocessing/5550156#5550156) answer to create my shared array and I understand from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25271803/1414831) answer that the array is locked. However in my case as I never concurrently write to the same row then a lock is superfluous and increases processing time.

When I specify `lock=False` however I get an error.

My code is this:

```
shared_array_base = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, 90, lock=False)
shared_array = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array_base.get_obj())
shared_array = shared_array.reshape(-1, 9)
```

And the error is this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-d89681d70c37> in <module>()
      1 shared_array_base = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, len(np.unique(value)) * 9, lock=False)
----> 2 shared_array = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array_base.get_obj())
      3 shared_array = shared_array.reshape(-1, 9)

AttributeError: 'c_double_Array_4314834' object has no attribute 'get_obj'
```

My question is how can I share a numpy array that is not locked each time I write to it?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11715314/1414831) thanks to [HYRY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772649/hyry)

Stating `lock=True` returns a wrapped object:

```
multiprocessing.sharedctypes.SynchronizedArray
```

When `lock=False` returns a raw array which does not have the `.get_obj()` method

```
multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_double_Array_10
```

Therefore code to create an unlocked array is this:

```
shared_array_base = multiprocessing.Array(ctypes.c_double, 90, lock=False)
shared_array = np.ctypeslib.as_array(shared_array_base)
shared_array = shared_array.reshape(-1, 9)
```

Comment: you could also try `shared_array = np.frombuffer(shared_array_base).reshape(-1, 9)`